# background-size: cover bug on Chrome

Tags: css

I'm trying this code. It works on Firefox 50 and it fails on Chrome Version 54.0.2840.99 m (64-bit), on Windows both fail.

```
.test {
    background: url(datas/images/3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover !important;
}
```

Here is a screenshot from Firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G088.jpg and here is the Chrome image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/56xWt.jpg

Comment: Could you provide an screenshot or an explanation what exactly does not work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems more likely that your '.test' class is inheriting some of its attributes from a parent element as it works fine in that version of chrome for me.

Try using developer tools in chrome to check what is having an affect on your class.

```css
body {
    background: url(http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: if I insert your code in <body> it works but on my item it fails :(( same problem

Comment: I tried to unselect all parents attributes but the prtoblem is still here